# Keeping a running total of score in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, dice, cumulative-sum

I am writing a program that rolls two dice; and then according to what is rolled, points are assigned; and a running total is kept. So far, I have this; but I keep running into an error of "int is not callable". Can someone please help?

```
import random
def dice():
    a = 1
    b = 6
    return random.randint(a,b)
rollOne = int(dice())
rollTwo = int(dice())


def greeting():
    option = input('Enter Y if you would like to roll the dice: ')
    if option == 'Y':
       print('You have rolled a' , rollOne, 'and a' , rollTwo)
       points = []

       if rollOne() == rollTwo():

           points.append(10)

           print('You have a total of %d points' % (sum(points)))

       if rollOne == 6 or rollTwo ==6:

           points.append(4)

           print('You have a total of %d points' % (sum(points)))

       if (rollOne + rollTwo) == 7:

           points.append(2)

           print('You have a total of %d points' % (sum(points)))

dice()
greeting()
```

Comment: Remove the brackets from `if rollOne() == rollTwo():`

Comment: Just to note for a pair of sixes, you'll get 10 points (for being the same) and then 4 points for both being six. Not sure if that's intended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from `dice()` is an integer which you have named `rollOne` and `rollTwo`.

They cannot be "called" like you have tried to do `rollOne()`.

In order to solve the error, remove the brackets from the line (which you have done in your other `if` statements)

```
if rollOne() == rollTwo():
```

becomes

```
if rollOne == rollTwo:
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this ,

```
   if rollOne() == rollTwo():
```

rollone and rolltwo are return values not functions